# How to generate a TOTP code in Swift Automation Testing?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I am new to Swift Automation Testing. I want to pass 2SV using TOTP. 
Do we have any function which takes the secret key and generates TOTP code.

I have a python script to generate TOTP code. Is there anyway it can be used in Swift?

Answer (score 0):

No, natively Swift doesn't support generating TOTP.

But you can use this library:
https://github.com/mattrubin/OneTimePassword

Comment: This can be done with CommonCrypto and CryptoKit, e.g. see here: https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/120918